# Is the set of Pythagorean Triples transitive?

Tags: relations, pythagorean-triples

Is the set of Pythagorean Triple's considered transitive? How would one prove its transitivity?

For the sake of formality, the set $S$ is defined as $S=\{(a,b)|\exists{c}\in{Z^+}\text{ such that }{c^2=a^2+b^2}\}$.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What do you think? What have you done to investigate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not. $(3,4)\in S$, $(4,3)\in S$ but $(3,3)\notin S$.

Comment: I was thinking this, however, I was unsure whether for transitivity all values $(a,b,c)$ must be unique in the definition: if $(a,b)\in S$ and $(b,c)\in S$ then $(a,c)\in S$.

Comment: They don't in general, but your S is clearly symmetric, so transitivity would imply reflexivity which would imply square root of 2 is an integer.  However if your eliminate reflexively by requiring a S b to imply a $\le $ b... it requires another look.

Answer (score 1):

$3,4,5$ is a triplet.  So $3*3,3*4,3*5$ and $4*3,4*4,4*5$ are triplets.  So transitivity would imply $3*3,4*4,X $ will be a triplet for some integer $X = \sqrt {(3*3)^2+(4*4)^2}=\sqrt {81+256}=\sqrt {337} $.

No such $X $ so not transitive.